# Javascript: Carry context of "this" when passing in a function as arg

Tags: javascript

I know a fat arrow can pass the context such as :

```
test() => {
    // the fat arrow passes "this" context into here
}
```

but I am now using videojs which has a onPlayerReady function passed in and the only solution I had was to make a reference to `this` and use it within.  I tried using a fat arrow here but it wasn't working.

```
let that = this;
let player = videojs('videoPlayer', options, function onPlayerReady() {
    this.play();
    that.$store.commit('test', true);
});
```

Comment: `test() => {` is incorrect syntax. I think you mean `test( () => {} )` (assuming `test` receives a `function`).

Comment: "I tried using a fat arrow here" - what happened when you did? What went wrong?

Comment: you've set `that` to be this, so just use `that.play()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.bind(this)` when the `function` is declared.

Like so:

```
let player = videojs('videoPlayer', options, function onPlayerReady() {
    this.play();
    this.$store.commit('test', true);
}.bind(this) );
```

The above code is equivalent to this:

```
const callback = function() {
    this.play();
    this.$store.commit('test', true);
};

const boundCallback = callback.bind(this);

let player = videojs( 'videoPlayer', options, boundCallback );
```

That said, the code below **should** work - I'm curious to find out why it doesn't work for you:

```
let player = videojs( 'videoPlayer', options, /*onPlayerReady:*/ () => {
    this.play();
    this.$store.commit( 'test', true );
} );
```

#### Update:

You said that `.play()` is a function-property on the `player` object - and I assume `$store` is a property in your object (and not `player`), in which case:

- Don't use a fat-arrow function/lambda, use a traditional anonymous function.
- Don't use `.bind(this)`.
- You will need to use a closure to pass the parent/containing `this` (i.e. the parent-component's `this`), but I recommend using a better name than `that`, such as `parentComponent`.

Like so:

```
const parentComponent = this;

let player = videojs( 'videoPlayer', options, /*onPlayerReady:*/ function() {
    this.play();
    parentComponent.$store.commit( 'test', true );
} );
```

Comment: thanks for explaining this!  Hmm, I was keeping the name `onPlayerReady` and doing `onPlayerReady() => {`  .  That is not needed?

Comment: @timmyLtus No, it isn't needed. You only need to use the named-function syntax if you need to refer to it by-name later on. Note that all "fat-arrow" functions are anonymous functions until and unless they're assigned to a variable or property.

Comment: I just realized that with this change, `this.play()` errors now since the  context of this is outside and needs to be the `player`

Comment: @timmyLtus If `this` inside the callack is meant to be `player` then don't use `.bind` and leave it untouched and use a `that` reference to the parent object.